# How to update a CursorAdapter tied to listview when number of items changes?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView backed by a custom adapter based on a CursorAdapter.

The cursor I give it is based on a list of Notes in the database (each note is a DB row).

Everything works just fine until I delete a note from the database.  I'm not sure how to properly update the cursor/adapter/listview to display the new data.

I've read conflicting posts on using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` vs `cursor.requery()` to refresh the UI, but neither of them seems to work in this case.  The only way I've been able to refresh it is by creating a new cursor from a new query and calling `adapter.changeCursor(newCursor)`.

Could someone demonstrate the proper way to update the backing data and then the UI (with psuedocode if possible).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to `requery` and then `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: I think the requery model has been deprecated as of honeycomb (at least not recommended).  CursorLoader is the preferred method currently.

Answer (score 1):

Calling requery will re-execute the exact query that was used to create the cursor - that is, it won't re-execute the actual method in your code. So if your method contains dynamic stuff such as sorting based on a preference, it won't be updated. In this case, you don't want to use the same query, you want a different one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me, im not sure its the best way.

```
c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM mytable", null); //same line of the first initialization
adapter.swapCursor(c);
```

I refresh the only cursor, I dont know what to do with a new one.
Also i dont understand pepole that answer with a name of a function.